# ClojureScript AJAX POST to send a json data

Tags: json, ajax, clojure, clojurescript

I am trying to implement AJAX POST in ClojureScript.

The following is the code i am using

```
(defn handler [response]
     (.log js/console (str response)))

(defn test-post [name email]
   (let [data {:name name :email email}]
   (POST "http://localhost:5000/Add/"
    {
     :format {"Accept" :json}
     :body (.stringify js/JSON (clj->js data))
     :handler handler
     :error-handler (fn [r] (prn r))
     :response-format {"Content-Type" "application/json;charset=utf-8"}
     }
    )))
```

When do i call the Post method. On form Submit? Also the post request is hitting the url but the json data is not present.

Comment: [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header) is a **response** header not a request header, it is useless in a request.

Comment: Where is `POST` coming from? Presumably from some library?

Comment: The POST is part of cljs-ajax library

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using [cljs-ajax](https://github.com/JulianBirch/cljs-ajax) for sending data.

What you really need in something like this:

```
(let [data {:name name :email email}]
 (POST "/Add"
  {:format :json
   :params data
   :handler handler
   :error-handler (fn [r] (prn r))})))
```

You can just pass a plain Clojure object as params, just set `:json` as data format (default is `:transit`).

The second question is rather open and depends on your setup. I think the simplest to use is [reagent](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent), here is a nice [example](https://yogthos.net/posts/2014-07-15-Building-Single-Page-Apps-with-Reagent.html) with sending form data.

Comment: I think i was missing the :header {                                     "Accept" "application/json"          :content-type "application/json;charset=utf-8"}